# How serialize and unserialize correctly an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

```
$array = array(
    'host_name' => array(
        'ip_add' => '127.0.0.1',
        'is_allow' => 0,
    ),
);
$str = serialize($array);
```

This value insert in my website. and read it using php function file_get_contents, I get this result from that page

```
a:1:{s:9:"host_name";a:2:{s:6:"ip_add";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:8:"is_allow";i:0;}}
```

and try to unserialize it, but it show a notice like:-

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 116 bytes in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin

Comment: I don't get any errors when I unserialize, [example](https://eval.in/private/20fd802a75b4f6). Are you sure your string doesn't have an extra space before or after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want unserialize you can use something like this:

```
<?php

$result = 'a:1:{s:9:"host_name";a:2:{s:6:"ip_add";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:8:"is_allow";i:0;}}';

$decoded = unserialize($result);

print_r($decoded);

?>
```

Is the same that:

```
<?php

$array = array('host_name' => array('ip_add' => '127.0.0.1', 'is_allow' => 0));
$str = serialize($array);

$decoded = unserialize($str);

print_r($decoded);
?>
```